# How to display a Hierarchy (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I have this project and it allows users to kind of create there own projects within it and save it off and do much more. Im doing this all in Java using the program Eclipse. Today I mainly wanted to know how would i go about displaying a Hierarchy? Ill be a little more specific, when the user creates a project it ask them where they want to have there project folder. Lets say they choose a folder name JavaProjects and its in there Desktop (I use windows so excuse me if it isnt the same on Mac and Linux) and within that folder they have a Scripts folder and an Art Folder and within there art folder they have a Texture folder and a Logo Folder (Im also coming up with these folders in my head as i make this) How can i have it where in my JPanelEast it display a format kind of like the Package Explorer In Eclipse? Would I be able to just scan the folder they put in and have all the folders and files neatly laid out like that? Or would i have to do something much more out of my knowledge?

If it helps here is my code, minus a menu bar and action listeners

```
package Engine;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButtonMenuItem;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestProjectBuilder extends JFrame {

    JPanel jPanelNorth = new JPanel();
    JPanel jPanelSouth = new JPanel();
    JPanel jPanelEast = new JPanel();
    JPanel jPanelCenter = new JPanel();

    JButton jButtonDebug = new JButton("Debug");
    JButton jButtonPause = new JButton("Pause");
    JButton jButtonRun = new JButton("Run");

    JLabel jLabelHeir = new JLabel("");

    GridLayout gridLayout1 = new GridLayout(4,1);

    public TestProjectBuilder() {

        setTitle("Test Project Builder");
        setSize(1400, 800);

        jPanelNorth.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        jPanelNorth.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
        jPanelNorth.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(14, 40));
        jPanelNorth.setToolTipText("North Panel");

        jPanelNorth.add(jButtonDebug);
        jButtonDebug.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jPanelNorth.add(jButtonPause);
        jButtonPause.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jPanelNorth.add(jButtonRun);
        jButtonRun.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        jPanelSouth.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        jPanelSouth.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));
        jPanelSouth.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10,200));
        jPanelSouth.setToolTipText("South Panel");

        jPanelEast.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        jPanelEast.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        jPanelEast.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,10));
        jPanelEast.setToolTipText("East Panel");

        jPanelCenter.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        jPanelCenter.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        jPanelCenter.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(56,10));
        jPanelCenter.setToolTipText("Center Panel");



        this.getContentPane().add(jPanelNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.getContentPane().add(jPanelSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.getContentPane().add(jPanelEast, BorderLayout.EAST);
        this.getContentPane().add(jPanelCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        jPanelCenter.setLayout(gridLayout1);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestProjectBuilder tpb = new TestProjectBuilder();
        tpb.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        tpb.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Thanks for all Help in advance

Comment: You will have to use [JTree](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JTree.html)

Comment: Are you looking for a [JTree]( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)?

Comment: Or you might prefer a [treetable](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=528).

Answer (score 3):

You might start with the code for [File Browser GUI](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Java Tutorial has a section on using TreeViews for this. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html

I post the link here, because this a bit to complicated for a simple answer.